# Problem with button remain "Reordered" after clicking "Reorder" button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, button, linkbutton

I need to make reorder button to remain 'Reordered' after clicking. When I click, the 'Reordered' appear but once the page refreshes, the reorder button is back.

I do have conditions where the Current Quantity cannot be less than Minimum quantity so that the Reorder button will pop up.

.aspx

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reorder" ItemStyle-Width="11%" ItemStyle-CssClass="table" HeaderStyle-CssClass="form-control-sm text-sm-center" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#2E5B89" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
 <ItemTemplate> 
   <asp:Label ID="lblReorderBy" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
     <asp:LinkButton ID="btnReorder" Text="Reorder"  runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block align-middle" OnClick="btnReorderIcon_Click" CommandName="reorderBy" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' OnDataBinding="btnReorder_DataBinding" OnRowDataBound="btnReorder_RowDataBound" AutoPostback="false"></asp:LinkButton>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

aspx.cs

```
  protected void btnReorder_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;

    int currQty = 0;
    int minQty = 0;

    if (Eval("CurrentQuantity").ToString() != "")
    {
        currQty = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("CurrentQuantity"));
    }

    if (Eval("MinQuantity").ToString() != "")
    {
        minQty = Convert.ToInt32(Eval("MinQuantity"));
    }

    if (currQty <= minQty)
    {
        lb.Visible = true;

    }

    else if (currQty == 0)
    {
        lb.Visible = false;

    }

    else
    {
        lb.Visible = false;
    }

}


protected void btnReorderIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String qs = "";
    LinkButton btnReorder = (sender) as LinkButton;
    Label lblReorderBy = (sender) as Label;

    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)btnReorder.NamingContainer;

    int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;

    btnReorder.Text = "<span class=\"fa fa-truck\"></span>&nbsp; Reordered";

    DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

}
```